# 500 Server error when redirecting from facebook login oauth

Tags: php, facebook, permissions, internal-server-error

I am running into this weird problem. I just put my application on a server, and I have a login with facebook functionality. When I click on the login with facebook it redirects me to facebook login and I put the credentials then submit it, but when I get redirected to the controller method which is supposed to redirect to my website home, I get an internal server error (even though the script seems to run since I can see that the session variables have been created). And the weird thing is, that it is working fine on my development environment (localhost). Any ideas? Is it a file permission issue, or PHP installation issue (Other features are working fine ).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest looking in your error logs as a 500 could be caused by anything.

Comment: how do you access that log? I was looking in the events viewer, but couldn't find errors related to applications running.

Comment: can I have a little more information about your server? what's your stack? where does your php.ini say your php error log is writing to?

Comment: Windows Server R2 2008, I have Plesk Panel 10.0.1 installed. PHP 5.2 installed. The php.ini says:
    error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
    display_errors = On
    log_errors = On
    ;error_log = filename
Now error log is commented out, this could be one part of the problem, what to put in place of filename? just the filename or the whole directory, if just the filename, where will I find it? thanks